# repeated IO on file atiumdva.cap interferes with application functionality

Tags: windows-7, drivers, java, virus, swing

Our java swing application runs on Windows 7 (32 bit) and is having some serious issues. Our latest candidate culprit is that the system, at random intervals, performs millions of reads of 288 bytes each, on the file c:\windows\System32\atiumdva.cap, pegging the system at 80% CPU usage for minutes at a time.

Can someone say what this file is, who supplies it, and what it is for? Or how to debug such an issue?

You should know that I have googled this file and not found anything authoritative on it. Just a bunch of posts from gamers about their video cards and what not. This is a very serious issue for my team and I need to learn something about it.

I am more of a programmer than a systems guy so I'm not sure where to look for answers to questions like these.  It affects me because a proof one way or the other would tend to inculpate/exculpate my application code.

UPDATE: Windows is telling me that the driver software is up to date.  OK, so what would cause this file to be read in such a manner (millions of 288 byte reads)?

[image: image of process monitor]

Windows indicates that the driver that is installed is the correct and most up-to-date available.  I don't think the driver is necessarily causing this.  It seems more like the victim.  What could cause the file to be read 288 bytes at a time?

Could this possibly be a virus?  Corporate Security is fairly intrusive about protecting its machines from viruses but possibly something's been missed?  Or could the virus detection process itself cause this kind of read to happen?

Update: driver information [image: driver information]

However, I must tell you that this only comes from a development machine that I have access to.  In the production environment, they aren't using an ATI driver.  If this is happening in production (and I don't know that it is) it must be something external to the driver that is forcing the capabilities to be read in this manner.

hardware ids: [image]

Comment: I suppose you got an ATI/AMD graphic card. `atiumdva` stands for **ATI User-Mode Driver Video Acceleration**. The code that should be reading that `.cap` file (some sort of capability table) is located inside the `atiumdva.dll` library file. What's the current driver version? What's the exact graphic card model and its [hardware ID](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hardware-ID)?

Comment: @and31415 - answered your question above, I think.

Comment: The hardware ID would be useful to pinpoint the actual model. To retrieve it, click the **Details** tab, then select the **Hardware Ids** property, and paste here the the value(s).

Comment: @and31415 - added hardware IDs.

Comment: A newer driver is available; before updating, it's better to check a few things first. Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7) and run the following command: `start /d "%userprofile%\Desktop" /wait dxdiag /whql:on /t dxdiag.txt` When done you should see a `dxdiag.txt` file on your desktop. Copy its whole content and paste it here: http://pastebin.com/ Then post the resulting link. When you're done, open a command prompt as administrator and run this command to check system files: `sfc /scannow` Report back the result you got.

Comment: I will do the above soon.  However, I must comment that Windows said I had the most recent available driver when I tried to update it.  Why would that be, if there really is a new driver available?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15909/discussion-between-and31415-and-steve-cohen).

Comment: pastebin of dxdiag: http://pastebin.com/Zqkyjevq

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

C:\Windows\system32>